# Initialize optional UIActivityIndicatorView in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  In my TableViewController, I want each cell to have a UIActivityIndicator when tapped.  So in my TableViewCell class I have the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var loadingIcon: UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

And in TableViewController I have the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "taskCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TodayTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TodayTableViewCell.")
    }

    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = task.name
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = task.description
    cell.timeRangeLabel.text = task.timeRangeLabel
    cell.currentTime.text = String(format:"%f", task.currentTime)
    cell.totalTime.text = String(format:"%f", task.totalTime)
    cell.taskIcon.image = task.icon
    cell.loadingIcon = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
    cell.loadingIcon.hidesWhenStopped = true

    return cell
}

override  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt
    indexPath: IndexPath){

    let cell = (TodayTableViewCell)();tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    print("tapped")
    tasks[indexPath.row].isActive = !tasks[indexPath.row].isActive
    if(tasks[indexPath.row].isActive) {
        //Loading.start()
        cell.loadingIcon.startAnimating()
    }
    else {
        //Loading.stop()
        cell.loadingIcon.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` but I have no idea why because it looks like I am initializing it.

I get:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
```

Here is the storyboard:

[image]

[image]

Now back to the error I was getting earlier:

[image]

Comment: What line is the error?

Comment: In which line is the error?

Comment: @paulvs see above

Comment: @MatiasJurfest see edit

Comment: Did you check that your IBOutlet is connected to the cell?

Comment: @MatiasJurfest I thought adding a connection is all I need to do?  Do I control drag onto cell?

Comment: @defoification Yes, you need to control drag into the cell to connect the UIActivityIndicator to the IBOutlet. 
By the way, I recommmend you to set that property (hidesWhenStopped) in the storyboard.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what is happening but if you have the ActivityIndicator being created in the storyboard, and properly liked to the IBOutlet, then the line: cell.loadingIcon = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray) is unnecessary, as you are just creating another ActivityIndicator over the last one.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the image, you can set that property on the storyboard. You can find on the right panel of your xcode.

If you still want to write that line you should connect the `UIActivityIndicator` to the `IBOutlet`

[image]

Comment: I get an error now on my `override  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt
        indexPath: IndexPath)` :(

Comment: It i really weird. Try to remove the UIActivityIndicator and add it again (In storyboard and also the IBOutlet)

Comment: same thing.  Ill try more later and let you know.  I think your answer is valid.  there must be something else going on